# I faced a issue while using the older version of FCM i.e 10.2.6 Unknown intent action: com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I faced an issue while using the older version of FCM i.e 10.2.6, I was not getting the notification, I googled
for this error and  didn't get any results regarding this issue, so I posted this if someone faces this error.

> Unknown intent action: com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT

update the gradle version to latest:

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1
```

Now it started working

EDIT : This is not a Question, its Info if someone faces this issue

Comment: now is it working or not? what is the question? have you checked your Manifest with proper integration and on which OS you are testing?

Comment: its working fine when i updated the fcm version

Comment: I am still using the 10.2.6

Comment: which android version are you using? i tested on 7.1.1

Comment: i am using API 25. but i also tested that on ODP3

Comment: i updated the android system image to 7.1.1 and then the notification stopped working